# Deploy NodeJS application to Heroku crashes with Permission denied error

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

My `postinstall` script compile TypeScript to `dist`. It works as expected after deploy I can see compiled files inside it. But after deploy (`web: dist/main.js`) I have this in logs:

`` Starting process with command `dist/main.js`
Process exited with status 126
State changed from starting to crashed
bash: dist/main.js: Permission denied ``

Why Buildpack des not have access rights?

Comment: Run it with `node dist/main.js`

Comment: My bad. I was thinking that it automatically uses node when it’s on NodeJS buildpack. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to execute the command `dist/main.js` instead of trying to run it with node.

Use this instead:

```
node dist/main.js
```